# Capturing Web Audio API data for socket programming

Tags: sockets, udp, webrtc, web-audio-api

I am making a video chatting web application using C# socket programming to transfer data. I want to use the Web Audio API to capture audio and video in my view page, but I dont know how to transfer the audio using sockets (which are defined in controller class.) Can the API be used for socket programming if I can capture the raw bits from the API?

(I've also tried using WEB RTC, but I am unable to create multiple peer connections. As my application involves multiple peers, I prefer normal socket programming.)

Comment: As cwilso noted in his answer, sending audio over the net is not an easy thing. You'll have a lot more success (and less risk of security issues) if you take the time to learn how to properly set up a WebRTC connection, and send audio data that way. In other words, I'd recommend figuring out how to connect multiple peers via WebRTC and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, can you just get access to the raw audio/video bits from getUserMedia - yes, you can.  (For audio, check out any of the input demos on webaudiodemos.appspot.com - particularly AudioRecorder shows how to get the bits from a ScriptProcessor node.)  But I would caution that streaming audio and video over the net is not a trivial task.  You can't really just push the bits over the wire with no thought to buffering (or adaptive capabilities, unless you can guarantee high-speed local network only).

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall work on buffering the raw bits and sent them through network